# CampaignMember.getSobjectType() returning null

Tags: null-pointer, sobjecttype

Whenever i am calling CampaignMember.getSobjectType() method , getting nullpointer exception. I tried to debug the CampaignMember object but getting null value object as well. Marketing User checkbox is checked on user record.

Comment: As you mentioned you are getting null value for the campaignmember object as well, trying to call a method on null returns nullpointer exception. Try to figure out why you are getting campaignmember object as null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a local variable or field in your class called `CampaignMember` (case doesn't matter in Apex) that will [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) (hide) the SObject type name and generate the NPE is it is null at that point in the code.

A quick fix is to use:

```
Schema.CampaignMember.getSobjectType()
```

But probably best to change the name of the variable or field.